# SwiftUI Scrollview scroll to next / previous item

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Simplified, my list looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to have a scroll to next / previous functionality, where each time it will scroll to the first visible item top anchored +1 or -1?

Meaning in the current screenshot, if I press scroll to next, `2` would be displayed where the `1` is. If I press Scroll to previous, we'd be back at the initial situation.

This should also work when the user scrolls manually. The first visible item should always define the next scrolling position.

So far I've only seen `ScrollViewReader` which only allows to scroll to ids, but I don't really know them since in my case I don't have a fixed order and I also don't know the first visible item.

Playground code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = 1...100

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Scroll to previous") {

                }

                Button("Scroll to next") {

                }
            }

            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(String(item))
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 300)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: it is possible!

The code below should help achieve what you are looking to do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = Array(1...100) // Convert range to an array
    @State private var currentIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Scroll to previous") {
                    scroll(to: currentIndex - 1)
                }

                Button("Scroll to next") {
                    scroll(to: currentIndex + 1)
                }
            }

            ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(String(item))
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .id(item)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: currentIndex) { newValue in
                        withAnimation {
                            scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .top)
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(currentIndex, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 300)
            }
        }
    }

    private func scroll(to index: Int) {
        currentIndex = index.clamped(to: 0..<items.count) // Adjust clamping range
    }
}

extension Comparable {
    func clamped(to range: Range<Self>) -> Self {
        return min(max(self, range.lowerBound), range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you scroll the list manually by hand and then click on the buttons it jumps to the index before the manual scroll.